# Database design to prepare data for AutoML machine learning & graphing

Tags: mysql, machine-learning, database-design, analytics, linear-regression

We want to start doing analysis on our data using some AutoML machine learning techniques. We'd like to create a table that a background process will combine and prepare our relational DB (mysql) so that it will be easy to export a spreadsheet that will be imported into some AutoML program (possibly h2o).

In our platform, users can perform several types of actions which we call "Activities". What we would like to do is track their engagement overtime from their account creation and pass this data into our AutoML program for analysis to determine if certain behaviors lead to certain outcomes (eg a decrease in certain activities leads to cancellation of their account).

Ultimately, we would like a spreadsheet that has the following format:

user_id | activity_type | week1_count | week2_count | week3_count | ... | weekN_count

Each week's count is the count of that activity for that user in each week following their activity. As you can see, the total number of columns will increase each week. Since the resolution is in weeks, the number of columns should be reasonable. We started 5 years ago (5*52=260 weeks) and maybe we'll go for another 20? (52*20=1040weeks/columns). Doable in a spreadsheet and pretty close to the max column count for mysql (1017 in our version of mysql).

However, I'm wondering if an alternate structure could be just as performant without creating columns for each week:

user_id | activity_type | yearweek | count

Are there any pros/cons to either approach? Particularly, we would also like to use this table as the source data to be fed to graphing libraries to show each activity over time.

Comment: What does this topic have to do with programming or development? I think you should use another site on the Stack Exchange network for these questions. See [All Sites - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and maybe [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It has to do with database design and data structures for machine learning algorithms. I searched and saw lots of other database design questions posted on SO.

Comment: Do not "splay an array across columns".  If you need to _display_ them that way, "pivot" during the output process.

Comment: @RickJames are you saying to have a column for say comments and in that column we store an array for each week? We don't care about display, but more care about the necessary storage for input into an ML model.

Comment: I don't know about ML; but in a database, having N identical columns is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is actually to do the following:

user_id | activity_type | yearweek | duration_in_weeks | count

Yearweek is the mysql yearweek() function that gives something like 201825 for the year and week of the year.

But for the AutoML we need it more in terms of distance from creation (eg to be able to tell something like 'When a user stops commenting after week 5 they cancel'.